# Clickable icon and text inside li

Tags: html, css

I have a icon and text besides icon.  I made icon clickable, but can't make text also be clickable. It seems simple, but I've tried different ways and can't make it work.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tetibuwofa/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cursor: pointer;` on the `span` element ;)

The issue is that the `a` element (which has `cursor: pointer;` property by default does not contain the text which is on the `span` element)

**EDIT**

As said @Justinas, it will not trigger the link that way. So you have to close your `a` tag **after** the `span` element.

And to keep the good style of it, [here's the working code.](http://jsbin.com/funaruniqi/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
i {
      border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px !important;
    color: green;
}
a { text-decoration: none !important; display: inline-block }
```

Comment: It will not trigger link click on span element

Comment: Work likes a charm. I didn't think about moving styles to `i` tag. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply close `a` tag after `span` instead of `i`

```
<a href="tel:+46706003303" class="">
    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
    <span>+1 234 567 89</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I have width and height for `a` tag.

Comment: Adjust the width if really needed.